# dotNet Spring Remoting Communication

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-remoting

I'm a `JAVA` developer and i need some advice :), so, i have a `JAVA` server and i'm using `Spring` and services are exposed by `Spring Remoting`. Now i have to develop a `DotNet` app that will communicate with this server, so, i want to know if there is any library in `DotNet` that accept communication `Spring Remoting` without big modification in my server.
I found this [.NET Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting) and i don't know if is it what i'm searching or i is it better to use  [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking this question for Java or .net?

Comment: My app is .Net and the server is developed with JAVA and i can add some modification on it if it's necessary.